# Crashlytics build id is missing

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, crashlytics

I am trying to merge fabric to Firebase Crashlytics in Unity project. I integrated all related SDK in my project and removed all related fabric sdk. I build the apk. I always got this error.
 I tried many ways. But all ways are not work.

```
06-02 17:30:52.452 28115 28115 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.UnmetDependencyException: The Crashlytics build ID is missing. This occurs when Crashlytics tooling is absent from your app's build configuration. Please review Crashlytics onboarding instructions and ensure you have a valid Crashlytics account.
06-02 17:30:52.452 28115 28115 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.onPreExecute(CrashlyticsCore.java:243)
06-02 17:30:52.452 28115 28115 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.onPreExecute(CrashlyticsCore.java:211)
06-02 17:30:52.452 28115 28115 E AndroidRuntime:    at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.onPreExecute(InitializationTask.java:44)
06-02 17:30:52.452 28115 28115 E AndroidRuntime:    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:611)
06-02 17:30:52.452 28115 28115 E AndroidRuntime:    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.PriorityAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(PriorityAsyncTask.java:43)
06-02 17:30:52.452 28115 28115 E AndroidRuntime:    at io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit.initialize(Kit.java:69)
06-02 17:30:52.452 28115 28115 E AndroidRuntime:    at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.initializeKits(Fabric.java:466)
06-02 17:30:52.452 28115 28115 E AndroidRuntime:    at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.init(Fabric.java:410)
06-02 17:30:52.452 28115 28115 E AndroidRuntime:    at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.setFabric(Fabric.java:368)
06-02 17:30:52.452 28115 28115 E AndroidRuntime:    at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.with(Fabric.java:339)
06-02 17:30:52.452 28115 28115 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider.onCreate(CrashlyticsInitProvider.java:27)
06-02 17:30:52.452 28115 28115 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1964)
06-02 17:30:52.452 28115 28115 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1933)
06-02 17:30:52.452 28115 28115 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6655)
```

Comment: Did you follow everything here? https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=unity

Comment: Hi @Wong, did you manage it finally?

Comment: I have this same issue when tried to migrate to firebase crashlytics

Comment: Hello, I fixed this issue. Can you guys check any Google, Firebase or Crashlytics error on your Unity Editor? When I import the SDK to Unity, I got some Google errors. I resolve this error and build the project again. The system will be automatically to generate the file `Assets/Plugins/Android/Firebase/res/values/crashlytics_build_id.xml`